# gradle project sync failed in android studio | how to fixit it?

Tags: android

im a new in android studio, I simply created a new project, and it says that:

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.
```

The Error Message Is:

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

you can see this screenshot :

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

please help me to fix this problem !

Comment: You seem to have some difficulty reaching some server for project dependencies.

Comment: Do you have project files under a network mount?

Comment: i can't understand what you mean, im newbie :/